# QItemDelegate using different itemRoles at the same time

Tags: qt, delegates, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I'm currently working on a combobox widget inside a `QTableview`. Which works fine and does what I want!

Except of ONE thing: the combobox uses the space which is associated with the `Qt::DisplayRole` only. But my item consists of a `Qt::DecorationRole` and a `Qt::DisplayRole` alltogether.

Therefore, can anyone explain my how to set the itemRoles which are occupied by a delegate in qt?

Thanks a lot
donny